# Where is the release apk file for cordova apps in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, azure, ant, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a certificate file using keytool command line. then i have updated ant.properties file ( under res -> native -> android) by adding the information i have set in the certificate file.

also, i have copied the certificate file in the same folder of ant.properties.

I followed the steps as mentioned in MSDN here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn757048.aspx

When i build in release mode in Visual Studio 2015, i don't see a release apk generated in the solution folder or inside the bin.

any help is appreciate it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To generate the release apk file in Visual studio, follow these steps:

1) Select Release build option.

2) Select Android from the solution platform options.

3) Select Device "This is a must step".

[image]

4) Right click on your project and Build the cordova app.

5) Check out Release folder in (ProjectFolder/bin/Android).

6) you will find your release apk file.

Comment: yaar, you solved the issue which I facing from 2 hrs.

Comment: glad it helped. enjoy :)

Comment: How would we do this on a build server? What switches need to be passed to MS Build?

Comment: If you want to use CLI to automate the build, use this command: cordova build --release android --device

Comment: this is for unsigned version and it won't work on average android

Answer (score 0):

If you build in command line with *devenv.exe /build*, you must have done this one time in order to work fine.
If you don't want to launch VS, you can add this line in your *projectCordova**.jsproj.user*** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Android'">
        <DebuggerFlavor>AndroidEmulator</DebuggerFlavor>
        <AndroidEmulatorID>AndroidDevice;Device</AndroidEmulatorID>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Android'">
        <DebuggerFlavor>AndroidEmulator</DebuggerFlavor>
        <AndroidEmulatorID>AndroidDevice;Device</AndroidEmulatorID>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```