# Create Android App using Apache Cordova and web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cordova, azure, apk

i am really new on this so i need some suggestions.

Using Visual Studio, i want to create an android application and i want to have flexibility so i will use [Apache Cordove](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html). It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development.

This is my client-side part and this part will communicate with the server-side [ASP.NET Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx) and provide datasources through [HTPP Ajax requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In this scenario, how can publish my app for testing and maybe after that for publish to outworld?

If i host my Web Service to [azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database) and create the [apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075824/where-is-the-release-apk-file-for-cordova-apps-in-visual-studio-2015) file will be work?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Android app using apache cordova requires a Android SDK.You need to install packages required to create and run the apache cordova using visual studio, There is another alternative for this which I found easy one use ubuntu linux with eclipse and Android SDk latest version which can be configured to create a apache cordova project.

Your another concern is regarding the calling of a webservice hosted on azure environment is as easy and same as calling a webservice's webmethods from javascript you just need to provide the appropriate url of the webservice in ajax call.

Comment: so..in some words is easy to setup an App! ty i will give my try